# How to add single short line, '|' as column separator in html table

Tags: html, css, html-table, multiple-columns

I have a problem that has been confusing me for the past day.  I have to create a table like the attached image.  I have to follow the CSS rules and however I cannot figure out how to draw the single black bar in between EDIT and DELETE.  I tried the | however it does not look quite correct.  I did a colspan=2 for the header and just got the grey bar per the CSS between EDIT and DELETE.

I appreciate any suggestions that you may have.

[image: Required output]

Comment: Use absolutely positioned pseduo element `content: '|'`

Comment: Andy, Thank you for the response.  Can you provide me with an example?  I am a bit confused with your recommendation.  I am a bit behind in my HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it using a [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) like this:

```css
button {
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}

button + button {
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

button + button:after {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<button>Edit</button>
<button>Delete</button>
```

Comment: I wish I could edit the CSS, however it is static for a class and I am unable to edit it.  I cannot figure out a way to do it without editing the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Addin this to the "edit" button in css:

```
  display: block;
  Padding: 0 10px;
  Border-right: 1px solid black;
```

Comment: I wish I could edit the CSS, however it is static per the class.  I do not think there is a way to do this in purely HTML.  I have tried about everything I can think of.

Comment: Put this next to your "edit" button <hr width="1" size="20">

Answer (score 0):

```
td:after{
        content:"|";
        margin-left:5px; /*To make it look good*/
}
```

do this